# How to create/write into a local txt file using Javascript or jQuery but no webserver

Tags: javascript, html, file, text, filesystems

I'm working on a project where I need to store the data in files next to the html-file but it needs to be runnable even without internet, and without any local web server.

Could somebody tell me how to create/write a txt file what I'll use as script in my html?

Comment: You can't do this if you want your app to run in a browser without a server. However you could use a server-side tool like [Node](https://nodejs.org/en/) (or [Electron](https://electronjs.org/) if you want a web UI).

Answer (score 0):

Build your app using [Electron](https://electronjs.org/) (or [NW.js](https://nwjs.io/)) and use Node's [filesystem module](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) to write your text file:

```js
const { writeFile } = require('fs');

const data = 'Some text';

writeFile('data.txt', data, (error) => {
  console.log(error || 'Done!');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Seriously I can't create a file on my computer even in the same directory where the html file is in without webserver?